# How to make counter which count mondays of specific month?

Tags: datetime, calendar

I want to construct a counter with two arguments - year and month, say `\tt{year}{month}`. The usage like `blah-blah \tt{2022}{6}, blah-blah \tt{2022}{6}` gives `blah-blah 06/06, blah-blah 13/06`. If the month has finished it starts the next one. The package datetime gives the opposite possibility: `\dayofweekname{1}{6}{2022}` gives the name of the date of the week.

Comment: you show `\tt{2022}{6},` being used twice and returning 06/06 then 13/06, can you clarify what this command is intended to do and what Mondays is it counting? I'm guessing that you want it to return the date of the first Monday of the specified month in dd/mm format then count how many times the command has been used (with the same month argument?) and incrementing the week. What would ``\tt{2022}{6},`\tt{2022}{7},`\tt{2022}{6}` produce? First Monday in June,  First Monday in July?, Second Monday in June?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle \tt{year}{month} is counter with increment one week. If it is placed first-time \tt{2022}{6} it gives the date of the first Monday of June - 06/06. The second time \tt{2022}{6} gives the Monday in the next week - 13/06 and so on. The \tt{2022}{6},\tt{2022}{7},\tt{2022}{6} will produce 06/06, 04/07, 13/06.  In fact, I need for the counter which starts from a specific month, say June, and counts all Mondays next months - July, August, and so on.

Comment: calling it a counter is confusing (as  counter means something completely different in latex) and the proposed syntax, giving the start date each time seems a bit weird and means you would need to  track an arbitrary number of separate threads. Simpler would be `\setMonday{2022}{06}`  which sets the internal date to first monday of the specified monh, then `\getmonday` ... `\getmonday` to return successive dates

Answer (score 3):

The solution uses a syntax more like what [David Carlisle suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646620/how-to-make-counter-which-count-mondays-of-specific-month#comment1611164_646620). We use the `pgfcalendar` package to do all the computations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfcalendar}
\newcount\currentjday
\newcount\daycalcoffset
\newcommand\findFirstMonday[2]{%
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1-#2-1}{\currentjday}%
    \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\currentjday}{\daycalcoffset}%
    \advance\currentjday by -\daycalcoffset\relax %find prev Monday
    \getNextMonday 
}
\newcommand\getNextMonday{%
    \advance\currentjday by 7\relax
    \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\currentjday}{\theyear}{\themonth}{\theday}%
    \theyear-\themonth-\theday
}
\begin{document}
\findFirstMonday{2022}{6}

\getNextMonday

\getNextMonday
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice use of `pgfcalendar`, but please remove the spurious spaces (try for instance `X\findFirstMonday{2022}{6}\getNextMonday X`). :-)

Comment: @frougon: `%` added. Fixed (I think).

Comment: Yes, this looks good, thanks!

Comment: @WillieWong Really nice and what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

A little modification of the answer above is suitable for any day of the week.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfcalendar}
\newcount\firstjday
\newcount\fistgday
\newcommand\fWd[3]{%
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1-#2-1}{\firstjday}%
\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\firstjday}{\fistgday}%
\advance\firstjday by -\fistgday \relax %find prev Monday
\advance\firstjday by #3 \relax %find prev day #3 (#3=0 is Monday)
\nWd 
}
\newcommand\nWd{%
\advance\firstjday by 7\relax
\pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\firstjday}{\theyear}{\themonth}{\theday}%
\theyear-\themonth-\theday
}
\begin{document}
\fWd{2022}{6}{0} \nWd\  \nWd\ \nWd 
\end{document}
```

The \fWd has a third argument which is a day of the week, 0 is Monday, 1 is Tuesday, and so on.

Comment: Please include a full MWE with a preamble and a document body with a brief example.

Comment: @Unknown Ok.  Done.